# Can SELECT use the results of a query to form the table expression in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, select, dynamic-sql

I have a table with an index of the other tables in my database.

Previously I iterated through this index to perform `queries on the tables indexed,` but as you might imagine, this is very slow for a large number of tables.

I wonder if it's possible to form a table expression from the results of a query on my index table and therefore write my query as one statement with the FROM using the `list of tables result` of the query on my index table.

ETA: I am using PostgreSQL v9.0. I am querying multiple tables with the same query by iterating through them one at a time (which is slow). I would like to speed this up, if there is a way to query all the tables with one table expression which is a list of all the tables selected from the index table.

My (simplified) tables are "tabledata" which contains a list of identical schema tables A, B, C, D, E, F, G and a boolean 'enabled' for each. I wish to query all the lettered tables for which 'enabled' is true; preferably with one query rather than iterating through them one at a time. Basically to query those tables returned by:

SELECT tablename FROM tabledata WHERE enabled = TRUE`

ETA2: I have entered below in the query tool:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_all_tables()
  RETURNS SETOF A AS 
$body$
DECLARE 
    _tbl oid;
BEGIN 
FOR _tbl IN 
    SELECT tablename::regclass
    FROM   tabledata 
    WHERE  enabled 
LOOP 
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE  '
    SELECT * FROM ' || _tbl; 
END LOOP; 
END;

$body$ language plpgsql; 

SELECT * FROM f_all_tables();
```

And get an error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type oid: "A"
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "f_all_tables" line 6 at FOR over SELECT rows
```

where `A` is the first table name in `tabledata`.

ETA3:

I have implemented the 2nd solution below and it works. Thanks
Example code:

```
CREATE TABLE tabledata2 
(
  tablename character(64) NOT NULL,
  enabled boolean
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE tabledata2
  OWNER TO postgres;

CREATE TABLE AAAAAA
(
  enabled boolean
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE AAAAAA
  OWNER TO postgres;
CREATE TABLE AAAAAB
(
  enabled boolean
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE AAAAAB
  OWNER TO postgres;

INSERT INTO tabledata2 VALUES ('AAAAAA', 'true');
INSERT INTO tabledata2 VALUES ('AAAAAB', 'true');
INSERT INTO AAAAAA VALUES ('true');
INSERT INTO AAAAAB VALUES ('false');

CREATE FUNCTION f_all_tables() 
  RETURNS SETOF AAAAAA AS  
$body$ 
DECLARE  
    _tbl regclass; 
BEGIN  
FOR _tbl IN  
    SELECT tablename::regclass 
    FROM   tabledata2  
    WHERE  enabled
LOOP  
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE  ' 
    SELECT * FROM ' || _tbl;  
END LOOP;  
END; 

$body$ language plpgsql;  

SELECT * FROM f_all_tables();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is far too vague and general a question to be answerable. You've given absolutely no useful information about what your database schema is like, what you're currently doing (other than a meaningless description), and no indication of what you're actually trying to accomplish. If I answer "yes, it's possible", will you award me the correct answer? What about if I say "no, it's not"? How about "maybe"? Please edit your question to provide sufficient details so that someone can try and help; as it is, it should be closed as "not a real question". Thanks. :)

Comment: Please, be more specific: table structures, volumes, SQL queries.

Comment: "I have a table with an index of the other tables in my database" It's very very *very* likely that you are doing something wrong here.  What is the problem you are trying to solve?  Maybe we can come up with a way of redesigning the way you're storing information so that this kind of construct is not needed (it should never be needed)

Comment: You shouldn't use the data type `character(64)` for table names. That's a blank-padded type, largely useless nowadays and may lead to errors. Use `text` instead. [More about character types in the fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gather from your comment that all your candidate tables share the same layout.

You already know yourself, that the proper way would be to have *one* table that holds all rows, possibly with an additional column to mark their type.

#### Retrieve rows from *one* table

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_table(int)
  RETURNS SETOF A AS
$body$
BEGIN

    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE '
    SELECT * FROM ' || tablename::regclass FROM mytables WHERE id = $1;

END;
$body$ language plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_table(42);
```

#### Major points:

- You can query a "table-function" (function returning `SETOF` values) just like a table.
- Your tables share the same layout. So you can define the return type and do not have to type a column definition list with every call.
- You must know that there is a composite type of the same name for every table in PostgreSQL. That's why you can use the name of one of the tables (`A` in my example) as return type and it will work.
- I use the [cast to `regclass`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html) for the tablename instead of `quote_ident(tablename)`. It protects against SQL injection just as well and it also works for schema-qualified table names like `myschma.mytable`. [`quote_ident()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) would be a good idea but fail in such a case.
- A function with dynamic SQL can never be defined `STABLE`. [More about creating functions in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html)

---

#### Retrieve rows from *all* tables

(All of the same basic type.)
First off: there is **no way in pure SQL** to do this with a **dynamic** list of tables.

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_all_tables()
  RETURNS SETOF A AS
$body$
DECLARE
    _tbl regclass;
BEGIN

FOR _tbl IN
    SELECT tablename::regclass
    FROM   tabledata
    WHERE  enabled
LOOP
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE '
    SELECT * FROM ' || _tbl;
END LOOP;

END;
$body$ language plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_all_tables();
```

If the members of this set of tables would **not change**, you could write one big ugly [UNION SELECT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION):

```
SELECT * FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM B
...
```

`UNION ALL` to keep all duplicates in the result.

Comment: I executed: `CREATE FUNCTION f_table() 
  RETURNS SETOF one_of_the_tables AS 
$body$ 
BEGIN 
 
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE ' 
    SELECT * 
    FROM ' || tablename::regclass 
              FROM tabledata; 
END; 
$body$ language plpgsql;

Select * from f_table();` and got the error:`{truncated} ********** Error **********

ERROR: query "SELECT ' 
    SELECT * 
    FROM ' || tablename::regclass 
              FROM tabledata" returned more than one row
SQL state: 21000
Context: PL/pgSQL function "f_table" line 4 at RETURN QUERY` I want to query on multiple tables.

Comment: Sorry for the terrible formatting; haven't figured that out yet.

Comment: @JohnSmith: I have tested the code I posted and it works for PostgreSQL 9.1. You neglected to disclose your version of PostgreSQL, so I assumed current version. Do you want to query multiple tables *at once*? Or one at a time? Please **edit your question** (press `edit` under your question) with your exact requirements. You can format text there. Do not put that in comments which are hard to read. You can add a short comment here so I get notified of your changes. Also add your version of PostgreSQL and the exact names and types of relevant tables and columns, please.

Comment: Erwin, Thanks so much for your patience and response. I have updated my question. Please let me know where it is still unclear.

Comment: @JohnSmith: I added another answer to my answer.

Comment: @ErwinBranstetter I have tried your suggestion but am unable to decipher the error returned as mentioned in the ETA2 of the question.

Comment: If it matters, I am using pgsql v9.0.4, not 9.1

Comment: @JohnSmith: Fixed a bug: I use `regclass` instead of `oid` now. Tested this with 9.1 and it works for me. Should work with 9.0 just the same. BTW, you added a couple of syntax errors to the code in your question - fixed those in the question.

Comment: @ErwinBranstetter This appears to be close to what I need as it is executing without error; but the return is 0 rows and just column headers. When I `SELECT * FROM A;` I get many rows. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm wondering if the fact that 'tablename' is a column name in 'tabledata' may be a factor in this not working.

Comment: @JohnSmith: It works for me. Of course `tablename` is a column name in `tabledata`. I don't follow? Maybe another case of mixed case identifiers? You understand that [identifiers are folded to lower case unless double quoted](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) in Postgres? `A` is just a placeholder. I would not name a table "A", I use lower case only for identifiers.

Comment: @ErwinBranstetter I didn't know whether tablename::regclass is some sort of system indentifier which might interfere with my use of tablename as a column name in my tabledata table. If this code is doing SELECT * on every table named tablename from tabledata, then I would not expect to get 0 rows as a result.

Comment: `tablename::regclass` casts to the text in your column named `tablename` to the data type `regclass`. I did explain in my answer above and included a link to the manual about object identifier classes. And what do you mean by `every table named tablename`? Does not make sense. Please be more precise. We are wasting time with unnecessary misunderstandings here.

Comment: @ErwinBranstetter Sorry for my shorthand. I meant every table named in the column tablename from tabledata. If I understand your code correctly, it is supposed to `SELECT * FROM _tbl` where _tbl is every tablename in tabledata where enabled is true. I just don't understand why that would return 0 rows when `SELECT * FROM A` where A is one of the tables in the tablename column, returns many rows.

Comment: @JohnSmith: It seems we are on the same page. What you describe should **not** occur. If `SELECT * FROM A` returns many rows and `A` is an `enabled` entry in `tabledata.tablename` then the function should return all those rows as well. Did you check in the same database with the same user? No mix-up with spelling, lower / upper case identifiers or schemas?

Comment: @ErwinBranstetter All of my databases have the same user: postgresql. 'A' is the only table with enabled=true in tabledata. Both `SELECT * FROM A;` and `SELECT * FROM a;` return 2574 rows, but the referenced code returns 0 rows with only the column headers shown with no errors. Not sure what other case problems could be causing this to not work.

Comment: @JohnSmith: I even went back to PostgreSQL 8.4, and it just works. What is especially suspicious is that the function returns the column headers, but no data. Are you sure there isn't some other table of the same name and with no rows in some other schema or something? Else you'd have to provide detailed table definition and function definition and show the exact values you have in `tabledata` and the output of `SHOW search_path`, so we might spot what you are missing. In your question, of course, **not** in the comments.

Comment: @ErwinBranstetter I have implemented sample code in the ETA3 of the question and it works. Still not sure why it does not work in my original db, but I'll keep working on it. Thanks so much for your help. Unfortunately I cannot flag this solution as the answer to my question since I don't enough reps.

Comment: Unfortunately after all this attempt to speed things up, at most using this function is only marginally faster (~10%) than iterating through the table queries one at a time with C code.

Comment: @JohnSmith: There never was a huge potential for better performance. As I mentioned at the beginning: the proper way would be to have *one* table that holds all rows. Reading multiple tables is never as fast. Maybe you could use a materialized view (just another table with redundant records) or temporary table to hold the united results of the function and reuse it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT tablename FROM mytables WHERE id = 42);
```

?  That's not really possible.

The most obvious way is to resort to a dynamic statement with EXECUTE.  You could write a function that takes the name of the table and returns all the columns for all the rows, which you then need to specify the column definition list for:

```
CREATE FUNCTION select_from_table(TEXT) RETURNS SETOF RECORD
STABLE LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM ' || quote_ident($1);
END;
$$;

SELECT * FROM select_from_table('pg_namespace') AS s(nspname name, nspowner oid, nspacl aclitem[]);
```

You have to think about how ugly this is.  If all your tables will have the same schema then you could clean it a bit by returning a proper type (instead of getting the caller to specify the big ugly column definition list each time).

Better still if you always want to filter in a certain way, you could make it do that.

But generally, you should also think about what you're trying to accomplish and whether you can do it in a more SQL way.

Comment: Something like:
SELECT * FROM (SELECT tablename FROM mytables WHERE id = 42); 

 ? That's not really possible
This is what I've already tried and determined does not work; it is essentially what I want to do. Unfortunately I am not versed enough to understand how your suggestion works and will have to research it to figure out whether it does what I want. All of the tables I want to query have the same schema. I know the more SQL way would be to have one large table, but when I designed the scheme I was planning on (eventually) having a distributed database with different computers working.